# Javascript img.onload() not firing and/or promises always pending on firefox but not chrome

Tags: javascript, image, firefox, promise, onload

I'm loading one or multiple pictures from local storage and putting it to a canvas on top of another picture.

In the code below I first collect all the loading images in promises that only resolve after the image has loaded. Second after all the promises have resolved I send the created image data.

```
var Promises = [];
        for (const selectedOverlayImage of selectedOverlayImages.values()) {
            Promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const overlayImg = new Image();
                overlayImg.onerror = () => { console.log(`Image ${selectedImage.value} loading error`); reject(); };
                overlayImg.onload = () => {
                    canvasContext.drawImage(overlayImg, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    resolve();
                };
                overlayImg.src = `overlayImages/${selectedOverlayImage.value}.png`;
                console.log(selectedOverlayImage.value);
            }));
        }

        console.log("1");
        var ret = Promise.all(Promises).then(() => {
            console.log("IN");
            let imageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            fetch("http://localhost:8000/picture-editing.php", { //Call php to create picture in database
                method: "POST",
                headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"},
                        body: `imageData=${imageData}`
            });
            alert('Images successfully loaded!'); //This creates a gain of time before the refresh, allowing the new picture to be present more often after refresh
            window.location.reload();
        }).catch((error) => {console.log(error);});
        console.log("2");
        console.log(ret);
        setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('the queue is now empty');
        console.log(ret);
        });
    });
```

On Chrome I am able to create one image consisting of multiple pictures.
[Console logs when successfully creating picture with wine as overlay-image, we can see the Promise.all function gets entered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fL6s2.png)

On firefox I am not able to create one image of multiple pictures.
[We can see the code never enters Promise.all while Promise.all never resolves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGQP8.png)

Thank you for your help!

**Reproduce the error**

Set the following in index.php.

```
<h1 class="pageTitle">Create Picture</h1>
<form method="get">
    <input name="modeOfPicture" type="submit" value="webcam"/>
        <input name="modeOfPicture" type="submit" value="upload"/>
</form>
<div class="wrapperPictureEditing">
<div id="getPicture" class="block1PictureEditing"></div>
<canvas id="takePictureCanvas" style="display:none;" width="320" height="240"></canvas>
<form id="takePictureButton" class="block2PictureEditing">
    <p>Choose Overlay Image:</p>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="overlay" value="wine"> Wine</label><br>
    <button type="submit">Take photo</button><br>
</form>

<script>
function displaySelectedPicture(input) {
  var selectedPictureDisplay = document.getElementById('selectedPictureDisplay');

  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
            selectedPictureDisplay.src = e.target.result;
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  } else { selectedPictureDisplay.removeAttribute('src') }
}

function takePicture(camera) {
    const takePictureButton = document.getElementById('takePictureButton');

    takePictureButton.addEventListener("submit", () => {
    let canvas = document.getElementById('takePictureCanvas');
        let canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
        selectedOverlayImages = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="overlay"]:checked');
        console.log(selectedOverlayImages);

        if (camera) {
            const stream = document.querySelector('video');
        canvasContext.drawImage(stream, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      } else {
            const selectedImage = document.getElementById('selectedPictureDisplay');
        canvasContext.drawImage(selectedImage, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      }

        var Promises = [];
        for (const selectedOverlayImage of selectedOverlayImages.values()) {
            Promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const overlayImg = new Image();
                overlayImg.onerror = () => { console.log(`Image ${selectedImage.value} loading error`); reject(); };
                overlayImg.onload = () => {
                    canvasContext.drawImage(overlayImg, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    resolve();
                };
                overlayImg.src = `image.png`;
                console.log(selectedOverlayImage.value);
            }));
        }

        console.log("1");
        var ret = Promise.all(Promises).then(() => {
            console.log("IN");
            let imageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            alert('Images successfully loaded!'); //This creates a gain of time before the refresh, allowing the new picture to be present more often after refresh
            window.location.reload();
        }).catch((error) => {console.log(error);});
        console.log("2");
        console.log(ret);
        setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('the queue is now empty');
        console.log(ret);
        });
    });
}

function setupVideoStream(stream) {
  const video = document.querySelector('video');
  video.srcObject = stream;
  video.play();
}

function errorMsg(msg, error) {
  const errorElement = document.getElementById('error');
  errorElement.innerHTML += `${msg}`;
  if (typeof error !== 'undefined') {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

function streamError(error) {
  if (error.name === 'NotAllowedError') {
    errorMsg('Permissions have not been granted to use your camera' +
      ', you need to allow the page access to your camera in ' +
      'order to take pictures. Instead you can upload an image.');
    } else if (error.name === "NotFoundError") {
        errorMsg('No camera has been found on this device. ' +
            'Instead you can upload an image.');
  } else {
    errorMsg(`getUserMedia error: ${error.name}`, error);
  }
}

async function init() {
  var getPictureHTML = document.getElementById('getPicture');
    var modeOfPicture = (new URLSearchParams(document.location.search)).get('modeOfPicture');

    if (modeOfPicture === null || modeOfPicture === "webcam") {
      try {
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true});
        getPictureHTML.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',
            "<video width='320' height='240' autoplay></video><br>");
            setupVideoStream(stream);
            takePicture(true);
      } catch (error) {
            getPictureHTML.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',
                "<p id='error' class='error'></p>" +
                "<label><input type='file' name='selectedPicture' accept='image/*' " +
                "onchange='displaySelectedPicture(this);'><br>Upload image<br></label>" +
                "<br><img id='selectedPictureDisplay' width='320' height='240'/>");
            streamError(error);
        takePicture(false);
      }
    } else {
        getPictureHTML.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',
            "<label><input type='file' name='selectedPicture' accept='image/*' " +
            "onchange='displaySelectedPicture(this);'><br>Upload image<br></label>" +
            "<br><img id='selectedPictureDisplay' width='320' height='240'/>");
        takePicture(false);
    }
}

init();
</script>
```

In same directory put an image named image.png, such as this one [image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zrwi6.png)

Then run the server with this command in same directory:
`php -S localhost:8000`
Visit localhost:8000 in Chrome and Firefox, see the console, on success "IN" should appear after taking a picture with wine overlay image.

Comment: We need to see executable code with reproducible error. I've just tried your code (using my image) and everything works fine in Firefox.

Comment: Excuse me, I added executable code to reproduce the error, I hope it is okay.